# ImageMagick remove background noise

Tags: imagemagick, ocr

In order to be better prepared for the OCR process, I want to remove the background noise on my images(typically this is a scanned image).

This is the example:

[image]

Is there with `magick.exe` command any approaches how to remove the noise from the images like this? If so, could you please show an example.

**UPDATED**

I use ImageMagick-7.0.7-Q16 on Windows 10

Answer (score 6):

Use -connected-components in ImageMagick to reduce the noise. (Unix syntax)

```
convert \
3foBc.png -threshold 60% \
-define connected-components:verbose=true \
-define connected-components:area-threshold=5 \
-define connected-components:mean-color=true \
-connected-components 8 \
out.png
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to execute the following command(on Windows 10 machine): `magick.exe convert image_59.jpg -threshold 60% -define connected-components:verbose=true -define connected-components:area-threshold=5 -define connected-components:mean-color=true -connected-components 8 out.jpg`
but it fails with the following error:
`convert: invalid argument for option '-threshold': 60verbose=true @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3009.`

Comment: Remove the "convert". In ImageMagick 7 it is just magick. In Windows, I believe percents need to be double as 60%%. Sorry I am not a Windows user. See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/windows/

Comment: I tried this solution on the image from this question
and looks like it is working but I also tried on the another *jpg* image and it's failed. Do I need to convert jpg to png or another format before transformation?

Comment: JPG has too many colors. Best to limit the colors to black and white. That is why I did the -threshold 60% first.