# ImageMagick for Windows, how to remove noise and horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: imagemagick, ocr

I have the following scanned image(this is a part of the image):

[image]

In order to improve the OCR process, I'd like to remove horizontal and vertical lines from the image and also the background noise.

How to do this with ImageMagick for Windows ?

Comment: Your text here is likely too small and the characters too close together for any OCR not matter what you do. Trying to remove the noise will distort the text even further. If you had larger text, then it might be possible to improve the image. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47989687/imagemagick-remove-background-noise/47998110#47998110

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but that solution doesn't remove the lines

Comment: I think you need to start with a better scan....

Comment: That method will not remove the line unless you increase the area threshold. But then since your characters are so small, they will be removed also. That is why I said that I did not think your image can be OCR processed successfully with such small characters anyway. Mark Setchell is correct. You need a higher resolution scan. I do not know if you can rescan that page or not.